# JavaScript MouseMove Event properties

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I read the Mozilla documentation page about the [MouseMove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) Event.
And in the properties table there are 2 properties that I do not understand how they work.

The **details** property which by description is: "A count of consecutive clicks that happened in a short amount of time, incremented by one."

What dose Mozilla consider consecutive, how long is the time between the clicks to insure the count. 
Can I configure it to be shorter or longer time period?

The **buttons** property, which stats the description with: "The buttons depressed when the mouse event was fired".

What is a depressed button?
Is it the button state at the mouseup event?
This is no mention of this phase or state in the [mouseup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) nor in the 
[mousedown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown)
So what is it?

Comment: _“What is a depressed button?”_ - one that is _pressed_ down ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `details` property give the click count in a short amount of time. The "short amount time" is the duration for a double click to be a valid input. In your particular case when you move your mouse over an element you will get a series of `mousemove` events fired however the `mousemove` event disregards the details property.. i guess moving the mouse and clicking doesn't make much sense. If you try it with `click` event you will notice how it works.

```js
md.addEventListener("click", e => console.log(e.detail));
```

```css
#md {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: thistle;
}
```

```html
<div id="md">Click</div>
```

it will count your clicks until the tiny duration for a double click is sensed. I guess you may change this time from your operating system mouse interface.

buttons property is very clearly explained in MDN as;

> The buttons depressed when the mouse event was fired: Left button=1,
>   Right button=2, Middle (wheel) button=4, 4th button (typically,
>   "Browser Back" button)=8, 5th button (typically, "Browser Forward"
>   button)=16. If two or more buttons are depressed, returns the logical
>   sum of the values. E.g., if Left button and Right button are
>   depressed, returns 3.

It gives you which button(s) is pressed when you have your particular mouse event fired. This time it makes sense with the `mousemove` event since it gives you the button numbers as said in the MDN above description.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, those are general mouse event properties.

Comment: @RuvenGam Yes right they are properties belonging to the mouse events not to the `event.target`

Comment: I understood the details property. About the buttons, you describe some sort of drag related functionality, I checked the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag) in Mozilla and found the buttons property there explained more clearly. Thank you @Redu